# inheritance with threads and child class, sharing memory

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, inheritance

hi im trying to understand inheritance in python for a project of mine and I have this simple script:

```html
from threading import Lock, Thread
from time import time, sleep

class P:
    def __init__(self, t):
        self.x = 1
        self.t = t
        child = C(1)
        t = Thread(target=child.runtime)
        t.start()
        self.runtime()

    def runtime(self):
        while 1:
            sleep(1)
            print(f"inside parent thread {self.t} x value is {self.x}")
            self.x = self.x+1
            

class C(P):
    def __init__(self, t):
        super().__init__(200)

    def runtime(self):
        while 1:
            sleep(2)
            print(f"inside child thread {self.t} x value is {self.x}")


P(1)
```

what I want is for the child class (C) to share all of the variables in the parent class (P). both will run side by side, I'm using Locks to access the variables. My problem is that I dont know how to access the parent variables in the child class. The current code has a problem that super is creating a RecursionError. I want the child class to have its own properties that the parent doesnt have, thats why I am trying to use super. Can someone tell me how to share variables between two threaded classes. In the end I want both child and parent to be able to read and write to the variable.

edit

the only way I found to do what I want is like this:

```html
from threading import Lock, Thread
from time import time, sleep
from random import random

class P:
    def __init__(self, t):
        self.x = 1
        self.t = t
        t = Thread(target=C, args=(self, 1,))
        t.start()
        self.runtime()

    def runtime(self):
        while 1:
            sleep(1)
            print(f"inside parent thread {self.t} x value is {self.x}")
            self.x = self.x+1
            

class C:
    def __init__(self, parent, t):
        self.parentVariables = parent
        self.runtime()

    def runtime(self):
        while 1:
            sleep(2)
            print(f"inside child thread {self.parentVariables.t} x value is {self.parentVariables.x}")


P(1)
```

but I dont know if there is a better way to do this, because I can see this style becoming a mess if my class C calls another class and has to pass its variables and P's as well.

Comment: This line `child = C(1)` has infinite recursion. It calls the Child's `__init__` which calls the parent's `__init__` which runs the line again.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how you're trying to introduce threading into all of this but a child class already has access to a parent classes methods and variables, granted the child class doesn't implement them itself.

Comment: @Axe319 that is my problem how can I include the parents variables without calling __init__? I put threading here because my implementation uses threads. If I remove the super() in C I lose access to the variables

Comment: @Axe319 What I want to do is have the a class call another class and share variables with the called class (ie they can both access the same memory address)